# THREE.js Scene Won't Update When Object Data Pulled From DB

Tags: javascript, three.js

So right now I have **a scene set up with 50 randomly generated boxes.** I add those 50 randomly generated box into a large THREE.Mesh, `drawnObject`. Then I add drawnObject into the scene.

The function `addPickingData` merges all those boxes into the same THREE.BoxGeometry, `allBoxGeom`. allBoxGeom is used to create the drawnObject.

```
var allBoxGeom = new THREE.BoxGeometry();
var pickingData = [];

function createScene() {    
    for (var i = 1; i < 50; i++) {
        var position = new THREE.Vector3();
        position.x = Math.random() * 700 - 350;
        position.y = 10;
        position.z = Math.random() * 800 - 400;
        var rotation = new THREE.Euler();
        rotation.x = 0;
        rotation.y = 0;
        rotation.z = 0;
        var scale = new THREE.Vector3();
        scale.x = scale.y = scale.z = Math.random() * 20 + 50;

        addPickingData(i, position, rotation, scale);
    }
    var drawnMaterials = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({ color: 0xffffff, shading: THREE.FlatShading, vertexColors: THREE.VertexColors, shininess: 0  });
    var drawnObject = new THREE.Mesh(allBoxGeom, drawnMaterials);
    scene.add(drawnObject);
}

function addPickingData(index, position, rotation, scale) {
    var geom = new THREE.BoxGeometry(1,1,1);
    var color = new THREE.Color();
    var matrix = new THREE.Matrix4();
    var quaternion = new THREE.Quaternion();

    quaternion.setFromEuler(rotation, false);
    matrix.compose(position, quaternion, scale);
    // give the geom's vertices a random color to display
    applyVertexColors(geom, color.setHex(Math.random() * 0xffffff));
    allBoxGeom.merge(geom, matrix);
    // give the geom's vertices a color corresponding to the 'id'
    applyVertexColors(geom, color.setHex(index));

    pickingGeometry.merge(geom, matrix);
    pickingData[index] = {
        position: position,
        rotation: rotation,
        scale: scale
    };
}
```

So that all works fine until I add a button to my html which calls my local DynamoDB server and pulls data for box positions and dimensions. Then, I create boxes with the data and merge it to allBoxGeom. My array of box data, `pickingData`, does get updated correctly with the new values. The **problem comes when I try to readd the drawnObject (with the new allBoxGeom) to the scene. The scene doesn't render the drawnObject.**

Here's my button listener:

```
updatePackageViewButton.addEventListener("click", function(err, res) {
    var table = "Boxes";
    var params = {
        TableName: table,
    };

    docClient.scan(params, function(err, data) {
        var boxes = data.Items;
        var barcode;
        var position;
        var scale;
        for (var key in boxes) {
            var box= boxes[key];
            barcode = box.barcode;
            position = box.position;
            scale = box.scale;

            var rotation = new THREE.Euler();
            rotation.x = 0;
            rotation.y = 0;
            rotation.z = 0;

            addPickingData(pickingData.length, position, rotation, scale);
        }

        var drawnMaterials = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({ color: 0xffffff, shading: THREE.FlatShading, vertexColors: THREE.VertexColors, shininess: 0  });
        var drawnObject = new THREE.Mesh(allBoxGeom, drawnMaterials);
        scene.add(drawnObject);
    });
});
```

And here's my render function just for more clarification:

```
function render() {
    requestAnimationFrame(render);
    controls.update();
    TWEEN.update();
    renderer.render(scene, camera);
}
```

I'm not sure where I'm going wrong here.

Comment: (1) Make `allBoxGeom` a `THREE.Geometry` object instead. While what you have will work, it's syntactically more clear, because you're actually working with lost of boxes. (2) Do you really need these to all be in one mesh? If you're trying to rotate them all together, you can create individual meshes for each box, and add them all to a `THREE.Group`, which is then added to the scene.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but if I decide to go with what you recommend in #2, I wouldn't need allBoxGeom anymore?

Comment: That's correct. You would create individual meshes for each box (you can even re-use the geometry and material objects), apply their respective individual transformations, and add them all to the group. Then, if you want to transform all of the boxes at once, you'd simply apply it to the group instead.